# Generate Url [symfony 2]

Tags: symfony

I want to send variables in the url but I don't know How can I send them like this: `url/page=1&element=a&...&...&...&..`
because when I use the normal symfony url , I don't get the variable in the correct place.

I made it like the default Url of symfony :

```
pattern:  /url/{a}/{b}/{c}/{d}/{e}
```

but if I send only "e" for example my code take it as "a"

Comment: You can not skip parameters in the url. How would you expect the url to look like? How could the router know what parameter you want to use?

Comment: this what I'm asking for how to do this in symfony, because I know with php I send for example url/page=1&a=2&b=3 etc so each variable is defined in the url but with symfony no

Comment: You can do the same in Symfony. Define your path as `pattern:  /url` and then in your controller action use the parameters as you want. But using "clean" url in this case is not possible...

Comment: How can i make this in Symfony, I didn't get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acces the url with query parameters if you want: `/url?page=1&foo=bar`. Your routing looks then very simple

```
my_route:
    pattern: /url
    default: # bla
```

in your controller action (you have to take care on validating the values):

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

public function updateAction(Request $request)
{
    $page = $request->query->get('page');
}
```

If you want a cleaner way, you should take a look at the [ParamFetcher of the FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/3-listener-support.md#param-fetcher-listener)

Comment: How I send the value of each variable?

Comment: What do you mean with sent? If you want to generate a url, simply generate it, like any other with all values. Every parameter which is not in the url pattern will be append in the query string.

Comment: Yes I made it, I have small question What do you mean with "Your routing looks then very simple", is this way no secure or what?

Comment: Bad translated, sorry. I mean, your route pattern becomes simpler (`/url` instead of `/url/{a}/{b}/{c}/{d}/{e}`)